# Fractional derivative

Tags: derivatives

It is mathematically, or symbollicly possible take the $n^{th}$ derivative of a function $f$  for values of n other than natural numbers? (or as I like to call it: *literal partial derivatives*). That is:

$$\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}(x),n∉ℕ_1$$
Perhaps for $n=\frac{1}{2}$: *"the the square root of the change  of $f$ with respect to the square root of $x$"*

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: The fact that the OP used the term "Fractional Derivative", a fairly obscure term, and yet asked this feels a bit suspicious to me

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm actually surprised as well. Just a coincidence though. A few seconds before posting I switched the title from "Literal partial derivative" to "fractional derivative" as it seemed to make more sense.

Comment: There is a reason its called a fractional derivative, sometimes we Mathematicians can name things without Euler in it, and then they usually explain themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non integer derivative of $1/p(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878707/non-integer-derivative-of-1-px)